# Ajax Call on Print View

Tags: javascript, css

I have a Site that renders a QR-Code for each of the page it contains.
Right now I'm getting the QR-Code when the Page is rendered. (its an ajax call)
The issue I have:

I need the QR-Image only for the print Version of the page, so the div is actually hidden except when CSS `@media print` is applied.

I was wondering if there is a way that I can make the ajax call only when users call the print version of the page... because I'm just wasting resources for something that is most of the time hidden.

I have for now no clue how to do it and would appreciate a push in the right direction.

**EDIT**

Well after trying the proposed solution with mutationobserver  I thought I found another way:
described in a [old blog from TJ VanToll](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/)

He proposes the the window .matchMedia can be used... 
Code:

```
var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
  if (mql.matches) {
     console.log('onbeforeprint equivalent');
  } else {
     console.log('onafterprint equivalent');
}
```

That is simple and exactly what I needed!.. *NOPE!*

The problem , I need the response to the "print" command to kind of be stopped, util I get response from the server with the image I need... But this is not the case... Now my print preview opens without the image...
If I open it for print a second time.. then the image is there... of course.. it has been loaded from the first try!

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to test this but you might be able to use a mutationobserver to check when the qr part becomes visible. And then trigger the ajax call.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Lru99de0/1/light/